# Why Google Analytics's code is so complicated?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

When one wants to include Google Analytics in his website, here is the code he has to include:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Why this is not simply

```
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js?id=UA-XXXXXX-1" async></script>
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it does more than that. But indeed, you could use

```
<script>
window.GoogleAnalyticsObject = "ga";
window.ga = window.ga || function() {
    if (!window.ga.q) window.ga.q = [];
    window.ga.q.push(arguments)
}
window.ga.l = +(new Date);
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js?id=UA-XXXXXX-1" async></script>
```

They just don't because that's two scripts instead of one, and dynamically creating the script ensures asynchronous loading even in browsers that don't understand the `async` attribute.

Comment: But the first script could be in the second one, no?

Comment: @Arnaud: Not if you intend to call `ga()` synchronously before the script was loaded. It's not necessary for those two `create` and `send` calls indeed, but IIRC all kinds of `ga()` calls are used in some sites, placed just right below the include script. `ga` needs to be declared immediately to start registering calls.

Comment: Ok, so the only purpose is to allow websites to make custom calls to Google Analytics? (and to support the 10% of browsers that don't understand async)

Comment: Yes, basically. Also, `ga.l` seems to be immediately initialised with a timestamp before the script is loaded, so that GA can measure some things based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is non-blocking this way. When the browser loads the page, it loads all of the resources and scripts.

With google's inline function, it inserts the script after the page has been loaded so the page load time is not increased.

Also, the `async` attribute is not supported by all browsers.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Browser_compatibility

Comment: It is supported at 90% (http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-async). If it was at 100%, would it be a good idea for Google to switch to my solution?

Comment: Not necessarily, you still have to have a script to send the page view. A lot of people customize their page views to attach additional data such as user type.